# Eigenvalues of the complement of a graph

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvector, adjacency-matrices

Let $A$ and $\widetilde A$ be the adjacency matrices of a graph $G$ and of its complement, respectively.

1. Is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $A + \widetilde A$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\widetilde A$?
2. Also, do $A$ and $\widetilde A$ have the same set of eigenvectors?

Thank you.

Comment: $A+\tilde A$ is the adjacency matrix of the complete graph regardless of what $G$ is.  On your second question, "yes" if $G$ is regular, otherwise "not usually".

Comment: @BrendanMcKay If $G$ is regular, how to show they have the same set of eigenvectors? Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer. In particular, I give a complete answer for regular graphs.

Comment: @DenisSerre Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Edit** (bis). There are two answers, depending on whether loops about vertices are allowed or not. In addition, the case of regular graphs is completely described.

1. If loops are allowed

The relation between matrices is
$$A+{\widetilde A}=J$$
where $J={\bf1}{\bf1}^T$ is the all-ones matrix. The first consequence is that the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ and ${\widetilde A}$ equals $|V|$ where $V$ is the set of vertices.

A second consequence concerns multiple eigenvalues. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, of multiplicity $m\ge2$, then $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of ${\widetilde A}$, of multiplicity larger than or equal to $m-1$. Just consider the intersection of the eigenspace with the hyperplane ${\bf1}^\bot$. In particular, this is a case where $A$ and ${\widetilde A}$ share common eigenvectors.

2. If loops are not allowed

Here
$$A+{\widetilde A}=K:=J-I_V$$
The sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is the opposite of that of ${\widetilde A}$.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, of multiplicity $m\ge2$, then $-1-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of ${\widetilde A}$, of multiplicity larger than or equal to $m-1$. Again, this is a case where $A$ and ${\widetilde A}$ share common eigenvectors.

3. Regular graphs

If a graph is regular and connected (thanks to Emil for having pinned the point), then $\bf1$ is an eigenvector, with eigenvalue $d$, the degree of each vertex. It is a simple eigenvalue because $A$ is irreducible (connectedness). The other eigenspaces are contained in $\bf1^\bot$, because $A$ is symmetric. Thus eigenvectors of $A$ remain eigenvectors for $\widetilde A$, with the same multiplicity. The correspondance between eigenvalues is $\lambda\rightarrow-1-\lambda$.

Remark also that $d$ is the Perron eigenvalue of $A$, $n-1-d$ being that of $\widetilde A$. We thus deduce
$$\lambda\in D(0;d)\cap D(-1;n-1-d)$$
for all the other eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: but $A+\widetilde{A}$ equals the adjacency matrix of the complete graph and not $J$, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi. This is a matter of convention. The question should mention whether loops about a vertex are allowed, or not.

Comment: @vidyarthi. See my edits.

Comment: thanks! deleted

Comment: @DenisSerre Thanks for the nice answer. What happens in the case when $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $1$?  Can you share some references for the part regarding common eigenvectors? Thank you again.

Comment: The orthogonality trick with $\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^t - A = \widetilde{A}$ and so $-Av = \widetilde{A}v$ if $\mathbf{1}^t v$ is really nice! (And perhaps even a counterexample to many answers, including mine, on a recent popular question about the virtues of writing $\langle u,v \rangle$ rather than $u^t v$ for inner products.)

Comment: I don't see how you get that for regular graphs, the eigenvectots of $A$ remain eigenvectors of $\tilde A$. Yes, $\vec1$ remains an eigenvector, and eigenvectors perpendicular to $\vec1$ as well, and in particular, there is an orthogonal basis of common eigenvectors. However, assume that the graph is disconnected, hence the eigenspace of $d$ has dimension $\ge2$. Then some vectors from this space (namely $\vec1$) will be eigenvectors of $\tilde A$ of value $n-d-1$, and some (those  perpendicular to $\vec1$) will be eigenvectors of value $-d-1$. But there are also vectors neither parallel ...

Comment: ... nor perpendicular to $\vec1$, and as far as I can see, these will *not* remain eigenvectors of $\tilde A$.

Comment: In fact, eigenvectors of $A$ remain eigenvectors of $\tilde A$ if and only if $G$ is regular and connected (hence $A$ and $\tilde A$ havce the same eigenvectors iff $G$ is a regular connected graph with connected complement). To see this, if $Av=\lambda v$, then $\tilde Av=(\vec 1^Tv)\vec1-\lambda v$ by your argument, which shows that all eigenvectors remain eigenvectors iff all eigenvectors of $A$ are parallel or orthogonal to $\vec1$. Since eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix span the whole space, they can’t all be orthogonal to $\vec1$, hence $\vec1$ is an eigenvector, ...

Comment: ... i.e., $G$ is regular of some degree $d$. Then, as I already pointed out, the condition also implies that the eigenvalue $d$ must have multiplicity $1$, thus $G$ is connected. Conversely, if $G$ is regular and connected, then the eigenspace of eigenvalue $d$ consists of multiples of $\vec1$, and other eigenspaces are orthogonal to it.